# Numerics with the Keldysh Green Function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, computational-physics, simulations, greens-functions

While numerically solving the Keldysh Green Function, the $t=0$ point creates some unusual complications (because of the jump for time ordered Green functions). Should one skip this point completely in the time discretization for the purposes of numerics? If one does so, can one still calculate the zero time lesser/greater Green functions ($G^<$ or $G^>$) by Fourier interpolation? I suspect that a simple Fourier transformation will try to interpolate the +/- limits for $t=0$ for time ordered Green functions and give their average as the result. Is this understanding correct?

On the other hand, I wonder if a sampling that includes $t=0$ can be taken consistently in a reasonable manner with epsilon shifts...any ideas, anyone?

Comment: You mean you have a problem with how to treat $G^R(t,t') \propto -i\theta(t-t')$ for t=t'? I usually choose $\theta(0) = 1$ and have no problem. I think there are other choices and the important is to be consistent, but it should definitely be possible to treat the point $t=t'=0$.

Comment: Indeed. That is the problem. So then, I guess, your advanced Green function skips $t=t'$?

Comment: @fra_pero For instance, if you choose a certain regularization of the $\theta$ function, how do you accordingly treat your zero time self energy correctly?

Comment: I never calculate the advanced, why do you need it? It should be easily related to the retarded. I should think more about it, but yes, probably to be consistent with $G^R(0) = -i$ you should take $G^A(0)=0$.

Comment: About the self energy, it also depends on which self energy you use. For instance, in second-order approximation for the Anderson impurity model, I use something like $\Sigma^<(0,0) = U^2(0) (G^<(0,0))^2 G^>(0,0)$ and similar for $\Sigma^>$. Then I just set $\Sigma^R(0,0) = \Sigma^>(0,0) - \Sigma^<(0,0)$.

Comment: Again, _probably_ to be consistent with this choice, you should set $\Sigma^A(0,0)=0$, but again, you should be able to eliminate the advanced component from your equations.

Comment: @fra_pero This probably corresponds to setting $0=0^+$ for time. I'm guessing your $\Sigma$ is coming from a conserving approximation that lets you have the same structure for $\Sigma$ as $G$ itself in your approximation, correct?

Comment: @fra_pero Also, does your technique produce decent results against benchmarks? For example, consider a particle hole symmetric situation with zero chemical potential, wherein we expect $G^>(t,t)= -0.5i$?

Comment: Maybe it's better to move to chat. I created a room "Numerics w/ Keldysh"